# Animating SwiftUI NavigationLinks that use tags

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I've added onboarding steps to my app using SwiftUI instead of a `UIPageViewController`. The root-level view has several steps:

```swift
struct OnboardingView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject private var onboardingModel: OnboardingModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                FirstStep()
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondStep(),
                                       tag: "second-step",
                                       selection: $onboardingModel.selectedStep) {
                            EmptyView()
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: ThirdStep(),
                                       tag: "third-step",
                                       selection: $onboardingModel.selectedStep) {
                            EmptyView()
                }
                // etc.
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }

}
```

The `OnboardingModel` keeps track of the `selectedStep`, so that changes to it will trigger the corresponding `NavigationLink`'s `tag`.

When the onboarding view starts up, the `FirstStep` animates in from the right, just like an ordinary push navigation. The remaining steps, however, simply replace the previous step without any animation. Adding an `.animation(.easeIn)` to each step does nothing. How can I make this look and feel like a `UIPageViewController`?

I should note that each step hides the navigation bar and title:

```
        .navigationTitle(Text(""))
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
```

but removing these lines doesn't restore any built-in animation that the `NavigationView` provides.

Click the screencap to see it in action. Note that only the first scene is animated in; the rest just appear, even though that is obscured a bit by the permissions dialogs.

[image: Screencap]

Comment: NavigationView does not work that way, navigation links in view are registered only for one level (that's why you see that effect - every next just replace already navigated one). Two have continuous navigation your every next view you include link to the following destination. Probably you better should consider TabView with PageTabViewStyle.

Comment: or just skip `NavigationView` altogether and switch between the different screens with a manual transition?

Comment: The reason why I didn't go with traditional `NavigationLink`s in a `NavigationView` is because some transitions will be triggered programmatically, such as when the user taps "Allow While Using App" for location permissions. Skipping the `NavigationView` and doing manual transitions faces the same issues. But I'll give both a try. Thanks!